# how to save the output to a text file for a python script?

Tags: urllib2, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make it so this script

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys, re, urllib2
import codecs

html_str = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)

for row in soup.findAll("tr"): 
  for col in row.findAll(re.compile("td|th")):
    for 
    sys.stdout.write((col.string if col.string else '') + '|') 
  print # Newline
```

sends it's output to a text file instead.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest? (if *nix):-

```
python file.py > filename.txt
```

Code wise though:-

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys, re, urllib2
import codecs

html_str = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)

file = open('file.txt', 'w')

for row in soup.findAll("tr"): 
  for col in row.findAll(re.compile("td|th")):
    file.write((col.string if col.string else '') + '|') 

file.close()
```